# Measurement current consumption of low power circuit

Tags: current, current-measurement

I have a circuit which has uC, Bluetooth module and some other ICs. Current consumption of it varies between 100uA and 20mA. I want to see current waveform using oscilloscope. I worked before high current measurement(above 1Ampere) using low-side sensing technique but not so small this. How to setup a small circuit to see current values ​​of each phase(sleep, active, transmission) separately?

Note: The circuit is powered by battery

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Measure Power Consumption on Extremely Low Power Devices?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/294180/how-to-measure-power-consumption-on-extremely-low-power-devices)

Comment: Have you watched this EEVBlog video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dh0xYu8YvaE&t=23s  where Dave demonstrates using the integration function of an oscilloscope to measure power consumption of a uC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use "shunt" resitor (low ohm resistor) in power supply line and measure voltage drop on it. Current is low, so resistor dont have to be real shunt resistor.

Comment: With a 10ohm serial resistor, i can follow the waveform. This is OK for me.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a current shunt amplifier.

It should do the job, make sure to use the right resistor value, following the gain of the amplifier.

Comment: And the op amp must be a true "RRIO" Rail-to-Rail In and Out type.

Comment: Please provide a link or a citation for the graphics in your answer. We want to be sure to give credit to the original creator.